# update our application to accept Inventor 2024 but have not been able to create the app bundles

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

We're trying to update our application to accept Inventor 2024 but have not been able to create the app bundles.

We are currently receiving the following errors:

> (UpdateUserParametersPlugin.bundle.zip): Failed The server returned
> the non-success status code 400 (Bad Request). More error details:
> {"Engine":["The Engine Autodesk.Inventor+2024 could not be found
> (Parameter 'Engine')"]}.

> (UpdateUserParametersPlugin.bundle.zip): Failed The server returned
> the non-success status code 400 (Bad Request). More error details:
> {"Engine":["The Engine Autodesk.Inventor+28 could not be found
> (Parameter 'Engine')"]}.

We have tried 2024 and 28 but both have failed.

I know that Inventor 2024 has just been released but has Inventor Design Automation been updated to accept the latest engine update? If so, what should we use for the engine number in order to create the app bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this endpoint : [Get Engines](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/engines-GET/) to get the complete list of supported engines.

Here's the list I obtained :

```json
"data": 
[
    "Autodesk.3dsMax+2020",
    "Autodesk.3dsMax+2023",
    "Autodesk.Inventor+2022",
    "Autodesk.AutoCAD+24_1",
    "Autodesk.Revit+2023",
    "Autodesk.Inventor+2019",
    "Autodesk.AutoCAD+22",
    "Autodesk.Test+Updated",
    "Autodesk.AutoCAD+23_1",
    "Autodesk.Inventor+23",
    "Autodesk.AutoCAD+24",
    "Autodesk.AutoCAD+24_2",
    "Autodesk.Inventor+2020",
    "Autodesk.Revit+2021",
    "Autodesk.AutoCAD+23",
    "Autodesk.Inventor+2021",
    "Autodesk.Inventor+24",
    "Autodesk.Revit+2018",
    "Autodesk.Test+Latest",
    "Autodesk.Inventor+2023"
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Alex. I'll keep an eye on the endpoint.